# Google In-app billing: Can't query subscription details

Tags: android, in-app-purchase

I have a really strange problem with Google In-app billing API.

I want to get the details of my available subscriptions to show their localised price on the UI. I'm using the IabHelper to query the details of the SKUs I specify, but the result contains no products, but after I purchase the subscription it's working, even if I cancel the subscription then and reinstall the app.

Here is my code:

```
    List<String> additionalSkus = new ArrayList<>();

    for (Subscription subscription : subscriptions) {
        additionalSkus.add(subscription.getSku());
    }

    iabHelper.queryInventoryAsync(true, additionalSkus, new IabHelper.QueryInventoryFinishedListener() {
        @Override
        public void onQueryInventoryFinished(IabResult result, Inventory inv) {
            if (iabHelper == null || result.isFailure()) {
                Log.i("subs", result.getMessage());
            }

            for (Subscription subscription : subscriptions) {
                SkuDetails skuDetails = inv.getSkuDetails(subscription.getSku());

                if (skuDetails != null) {
                    subscription.setLocalizedPrice(skuDetails.getPrice());
                    Log.i("subs", subscription.getLocalizedPrice());
                }

            }
        }
    });
```

I have everything set up right about the In-app billing process. My products are active, I have a published beta APK, I can even get the details of my managed products, and purchase managed products and subscriptions, but this isn't working.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you're using the latest version of `IabHelper` class, you should note that the function arguments relevant to additional skus to query are split to `moreItemSkus` (`PRODUCT` skus) and `moreSubsSkus` (`SUBSCRIPTIONS` skus).

```
public void queryInventoryAsync(final boolean querySkuDetails, final List<String> moreItemSkus,
        final List<String> moreSubsSkus, final QueryInventoryFinishedListener listener)
```

In your case, your call should be

```
iabHelper.queryInventoryAsync(true, null, additionalSkus, new IabHelper.QueryInventoryFinishedListener() ...
```

Comment: Thanks, that helped, though there wasn't such an async method in my IabHelper class, only a sync queryInventory(boolean, List, List), but I changed the async method to call this, and now it works.